# Why is Ubuntu positioning new windows beneath the menu bar?

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, window-manager

I was messing around with CompizConfig Settings Manager recently and I'm not really sure what I did to cause this issue, but now all new windows are opened at 0, 0. This means the title bar is positioned beneath the menu bar in the window z-order, making it very difficult to grab and move the window.

Here's a screenie that may explain it a little better:

[image]

I was pretty much just experimenting in CompizConfig Settings Manager, I reversed any changes I made (to my knowledge), but I may have overlooked something. How can I fix this?

Comment: try unity --replace in terminal or in the tty1

Comment: @Prasad: nope, didn't work. Note: I have restarted my computer since, in hopes that it was a bug that would be fixed by a reboot.

Comment: sometimes, compiz plays with us a bit. when you click on a window, it'll disappear from there and appear in a new place... next time you know what to do, Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Login using credentials.
2. Enter

   ```
   sudo stop lightdm
   ```
3. Enter

   ```
   unity --reset
   ```
4. Reboot the system using

   ```
   sudo reboot now
   ```
5. If even after reboot, it is the same situation, open a terminal.
6. Type in `ccsm`.
7. Now check '*Unity Plugin*'. It might have got unchecked. Once checked, it will fix everything.

Next time take a back up in ccsm working profile.

Comment: `unity --reset` fixed it, albeit all my settings were lost. It's not a major issue, though, and you're right; I should have made a backup! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11):

I opened the CompizConfig Setting Manager and enabled **Place Windows** plugin.

Comment: This worked for me / is an appropriate answer for 16.04

Comment: It still seems to be a problem and `ccsm` does not give a hint about this issue. Thank you, for your solution.